loid googlebot ... token with third-party cookie blocked
I just found out about the third-party cookie deprecation and found out that one request was blocked in my website.
I have turned on "Test Third Party Cookie Phaseout".
The request was for fetching the google user profile from https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/..., and it request a cookie with name loid, value googlebot000000000..., and domain .googleusercontent.com.
I have no idea what this is, and should I be worried about this?
Moreover, I'd like to fix this issue or mute it (if it is not a problem).
